# How can I execute a SQL Server stored procedure from a Batch file and get the Output parameter value?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, batch-file, cmd, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL Server stored procedure that has an output parameter

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @outputx int output
AS
    SELECT @outputx = 123
```

When I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns 123:

```
DECLARE @outputx int
EXEC test @outputx output

SELECT @outputx  --> returns 123
```

I need to call this stored procedure from a batch file or PowerShell.

I use this code in a `.BAT` file (I use `OSQL`):

```
SET tempfile = "C:\myFolder\tempfile.txt"
SET outputx = 0
SET Cmd = EXEC test @outputx output;
SET Cmd = "%Cmd%"

OSQL -S myDBServer -d myDbName -E -e -p -b -Q %Cmd% >%tempfile%
```

When I checked `tempfile.txt`, it says this:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Server myDBServer, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@outputx".
>   EXEC test @outputx output;

How can I execute a SQL Server stored procedure from a batch file and get the output parameter value?

Thank you

Comment: The correct syntax for cmd.exe, i.e. your batch file, would be `SET "tempfile=C:\myFolder\tempfile.txt"`, `SET "outputx=0"`, `SET "cmnd=EXEC test @outputx output;"`, and `OSQL -S myDBServer -d myDbName -E -e -p -b -Q "%cmnd%" >"%tempfile%"`. _Note, this is not an answer to your question, simply the correct syntax for what you have posted as your own batch file code._

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the SqlServer module for PowerShell?  After installing that module, you have access to the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet.  You can use this cmdlet to retrieve anything that will run in SQLMgr.

```
$ReturnValue = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Query $QueryString
```

There are other commands in that module including commands to read and write tables and views.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I need to use Integrated Security (Trusted Connection), instead of using username and pwd. Can I do that with sqlcmd ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15 says that "the -G option only applies to Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Warehouse".

Comment: I do not have personal experience with using the Integrated Security, however check out Example #9 on [the Microsoft documentation site for Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) where it mentions Integrated Security=True.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, and it gave me the error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'. 
But, using "-E" in the cmd seems to work:
sqlcmd -Q"SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM myTbl" -SMyServer -dMyDB -E